# Suggestions needed for replacement of Oracle SSO 10g in an 11g environment

Tags: oracle10g, oracle11g, single-sign-on

We're currently using the SSO component of Oracle 10g App Server to authenticate users on our external / internet facing client "portal" (think similar to online banking)

SSO uses Oracle Internet Directory to store it's data, and we've been able to use PL/SQL and Java to access and modify the data held in OID (e.g create/drop users, change/verify passwords etc)

With the advent of 11g, Oracle appears to have "orphaned" SSO… it is available, but only as an add-on, and it appears to have been superseded by Oracle Access Manager.  I'm guessing that it will have been dropped together by 12g.  Plus it looks pretty difficult to install and get running correctly.

So, I'm wondering if anyone has any experience of having had the same migration problem as us?  If so, what did you do?

Alternatively, does anyone have any experience of doing something similar using Oracle Access Manager?  Do you think it will do what we want?

Or is there a better road to go down?  Is there something else I should be considering?

Sorry for the very broad question, but it's one of those situations where a person's experience of what does + doesn’t work can make an enormous difference to us making some progress in a timely fashion.  Thanks.

Comment: What did you end up doing with your 10g SSO environment and how did it go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my knowledge, Oracle Internet Directory (OID) is an LDAP compliant directory whereas Oracle Access Manager (OAM) is much more complex and consists of two main systems:

1. Identity System (users, groups,
   workflows)
2. Access System (single/multi domain
   SSO solution for Web and non-Web
   based applications).

Access Manager relies on an Identity Server which is a stand-alone server process that communicates with **any** Directory Server (AD, OID, Sun Directory server..).

So you can use the new OAM and link it with your existing OID... to retrieve users/groups and metadata. All that you could do with OID will be doable with OAM as it brings more abstraction layers.

But in my opinion, and considering your case, directly accessing LDAP servers (OID, AD, etc) and using a light and "home made" SSO system is cheaper than relying on those big systems.... I think OAM is a usefull solution when you have lots of heterogeneous applications (web, non web, mobile, ...) and/or multiple organizations/domains with links and/or you need a very scalable approach.

Comment: I don't really want to build an SSO system...  Do you know of any "light" ones we could use?

Comment: The 10g SSO is not really a light system on itself, and any following version is not going to be lighter. Don't think that the software changes in a big way, because the name does. It may, it may not. But, having said that, there's lot's of improvement in that sort of software (Oracle SSO). So, it's not bad, but when you are looking for light software, and you miss out on knowledge and/or time, there must be others. No, there are others. Take in mind Oracle SSO/OAM will be better suited to serve Oracle applications, but that's a price to pay.